# Fragment 2 triggered before Fragment 1 in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created three fragment in a single activity with use of FragmentPagerAdapter.In first fragment I used button click move to on second fragment.While debugging first it was triggered to the 3rd fragment and then only it was returning to 2nd fragment.

```
  public class Main_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    /**
     *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
     */

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff);

    /**
     * Lets inflate the very first fragment
     * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
     */

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();
    /**
     * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
     */


    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

}
```

}

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    final Button bt_view = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BT_view);
    bt_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), BookList_Activity.class));

        }
    });
    final Button bt_add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BT_AddBook);
    bt_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

}

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


Button bt_next;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectlocation_layout, container, false);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    bt_next = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BT_continue);


    // Implement OnClick,OnTouch and OnItemSelected Events

    //OnItemSelected Listner


    // OnClick Listner
    bt_next.setOnClickListener(this);


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.BT_continue:

                viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

            break;

    }
}
```

}

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {
```

View rootView;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addbook_layout, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: please. do it step by step. edit your question using this: 1) what you want 2) what you tried 3) which problem is showing. It's really confusing and honestly I can't really get any sense in this question..

Comment: Where are you using `FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();` ?

Comment: where do you set adapter to your View pager ?!

Comment: Thanks for reply .declaration of adapter was the mistake .I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);` in your `onCreateView()` method.